# How to convert date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application, in JSON responses from controller, dates are coming as `2015-06-22T18:08:22+05:30`. I want to convert the date into `22-06-2015, 06:08 PM` format in Javascript. I checked may resources in Stackoverflow but none is working. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: it is not hard to do that using js but it would be much easier to do the formatting the server side before put it into JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use date.format [library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Here's a example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srj90c4f/)

`var date = new Date("2015-06-22T18:08:22+05:30");
var dateString = date.format("dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM:ss TT Z");
alert(dateString);`

Also it would be better to format it on server side if you dont want to include extra libraries

Answer (score 1):

[moment](http://momentjs.com) is a very good library for dealing with date.

```
console.log(moment('2015-06-22T18:08:22+05:30').format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss a'));

> 22-06-2015 7:38:22 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Two Ways:

1. Do the conversion in the Rails and send the value via JSON (using strftime or u can use Date.strptime or Time.strptime)

Code:

```
User.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

2. Doing the conversion in Front End using Moment Js:

Code:

```
console.log(moment('2015-06-22T18:08:22+05:30').format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss a'));
```